# Responsive Layout Using Media Queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I tried to implement my first Media Query and I cannot understand why it has had no effect. I have 4 columns (flex items) and I am trying to reduce this to 2 columns (flex Items)  on screens under 800px.

I followed the w3schools example.

I would be very grateful if somebody could look at my code and tell me what I am missing.

https://codepen.io/mrlondon/project/live/DdvONp/

I am trying to build my first static website. I am now trying to figure out how to make it responsive. It won't let me post this without adding more detail but I just want to know what's wrong with this media query.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and(max-width:800px) {
  .column {
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 0 1%;
  }
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url("wallpaper2.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #f0c330;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.lastlist {
  padding-right: 65px;
}

.nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f0c330;
}

.nav:hover {
  color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  background: pink;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: max-content;
  padding: 2%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column {
  flex: 0 1 25%;
  padding: 0 1%;
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.column img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 2px #f0c330;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <nav>
    <h1>Daniel Savva</h1>
    <ul>
      <li> <a class="nav" href="#">  Home</a> </li>
      <li> <a class="nav" href="#">  Gallery</a> </li>
      <li> <a class="nav" href="#">  About</a> </li>
      <li class="lastlist"> <a class="nav" href="#">  Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="column">

      <div class="gallery">

        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jySfU10IQu4">
          <img src="picture1.jpg" alt="Picture1">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-9dxYcH7sg">
          <img src="picture55.jpg" alt="picture55">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEgX64n3T7g">
          <img src="picture10.jpg" alt="picture10">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hF-QqKiT1bI">
          <img src="picture2.jpg" alt="picture2">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUvVdTlA23w">
          <img src="picture77.jpg" alt="picture77">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVL-zZnD3VU">
          <img src="picture11.jpg" alt="picture11">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="column">

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_9tX4eHztY">
          <img src="picture3.jpg" alt="picture3">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nu__TzWfpss">
          <img src="picture66.jpg" alt="picture66">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S71_vIMQ0YY">
          <img src="picture12.jpg" alt="picture12">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_9tX4eHztY">
          <img src="picture45.jpg" alt="picture45">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Soa3gO7tL-c">
          <img src="picture9.jpg" alt="picture9">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FrOQC-zEog">
          <img src="picture13.jpg" alt="picture13">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space in between `and` & `(max-width-:800px)` .

You also need to place the media querie at the end or increase the selector weight , else , the other rule for `.column {flex: xx}` overides it .

example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .row .column {/* increase selector wheight or send me after .column selector */
    flex  :  50%;
    padding: 0 1%;
  }
}


body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url("wallpaper2.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #f0c330;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.lastlist {
  padding-right: 65px;
}

.nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f0c330;
}

.nav:hover {
  color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  background: pink;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: max-content;
  padding: 2%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column {
  flex: 0 1 25%;
  padding: 0 1%;
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.column img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 2px #f0c330;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <nav>
    <h1>Daniel Savva</h1>
    <ul>
      <li> <a class="nav" href="#">  Home</a> </li>
      <li> <a class="nav" href="#">  Gallery</a> </li>
      <li> <a class="nav" href="#">  About</a> </li>
      <li class="lastlist"> <a class="nav" href="#">  Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="column">

      <div class="gallery">

        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jySfU10IQu4">
          <img src="picture1.jpg" alt="Picture1">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-9dxYcH7sg">
          <img src="picture55.jpg" alt="picture55">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEgX64n3T7g">
          <img src="picture10.jpg" alt="picture10">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hF-QqKiT1bI">
          <img src="picture2.jpg" alt="picture2">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUvVdTlA23w">
          <img src="picture77.jpg" alt="picture77">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVL-zZnD3VU">
          <img src="picture11.jpg" alt="picture11">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="column">

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_9tX4eHztY">
          <img src="picture3.jpg" alt="picture3">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nu__TzWfpss">
          <img src="picture66.jpg" alt="picture66">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S71_vIMQ0YY">
          <img src="picture12.jpg" alt="picture12">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_9tX4eHztY">
          <img src="picture45.jpg" alt="picture45">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Soa3gO7tL-c">
          <img src="picture9.jpg" alt="picture9">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FrOQC-zEog">
          <img src="picture13.jpg" alt="picture13">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add meta tag to your header

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, all you need to add is a media query like this (the `max-width` value in it should be adjusted to your actual requirements):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    flex: 0 1 50%;
    padding: 0 1%;
  }
}
```

It sets the width of `.column` to 50% (instead of 25%), which results in a two-column layout instead of four columns for screens which are 600px wide or less.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and(max-width:800px) {
  .column {
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 0 1%;
  }
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url("wallpaper2.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #f0c330;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.lastlist {
  padding-right: 65px;
}

.nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f0c330;
}

.nav:hover {
  color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  background: pink;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: max-content;
  padding: 2%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column {
  flex: 0 1 25%;
  padding: 0 1%;
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.column img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 2px #f0c330;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    flex: 0 1 50%;
    padding: 0 1%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <nav>
    <h1>Daniel Savva</h1>
    <ul>
      <li> <a class="nav" href="#">  Home</a> </li>
      <li> <a class="nav" href="#">  Gallery</a> </li>
      <li> <a class="nav" href="#">  About</a> </li>
      <li class="lastlist"> <a class="nav" href="#">  Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="column">

      <div class="gallery">

        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jySfU10IQu4">
          <img src="picture1.jpg" alt="Picture1">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-9dxYcH7sg">
          <img src="picture55.jpg" alt="picture55">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEgX64n3T7g">
          <img src="picture10.jpg" alt="picture10">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hF-QqKiT1bI">
          <img src="picture2.jpg" alt="picture2">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUvVdTlA23w">
          <img src="picture77.jpg" alt="picture77">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVL-zZnD3VU">
          <img src="picture11.jpg" alt="picture11">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="column">

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_9tX4eHztY">
          <img src="picture3.jpg" alt="picture3">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nu__TzWfpss">
          <img src="picture66.jpg" alt="picture66">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S71_vIMQ0YY">
          <img src="picture12.jpg" alt="picture12">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_9tX4eHztY">
          <img src="picture45.jpg" alt="picture45">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Soa3gO7tL-c">
          <img src="picture9.jpg" alt="picture9">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FrOQC-zEog">
          <img src="picture13.jpg" alt="picture13">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```